# Why does my new version of Firefox only run from the GUI but not the terminal?

Tags: firefox, launcher, symbolic-link

This all started when I wanted to get rid of the title bar in Firefox. I looked up how to solve this and all the answers gave a simple solution along the lines of "check this box in your customization menu". However, that box didn't exist for me. Luckily, I discovered a post addressing this issue:

> Note that the Firefox version from the Ubuntu repositories that you
> appear to be using might behave differently and might not support
> client-side-decoration. Try the Firefox version from the official
> Mozilla server if you currently use a version from the repositories of
> your Linux distribution.

So I followed the suggestion, downloaded the .tar.bz2, extracted it, and ran it through the GUI.

[image]

Success! This version of Firefox allowed me to check the box to hide the title bar. I went about editing the .desktop file's exec line to point to `~/firefox/firefox` so the dock icon would run this version. I opened FF from my dock panel, but it had opened the snap version. Odd... I tried running `~/firefox/firefox` from the terminal, but it opened the snap version again. I checked my sanity and opened it from the GUI, absolutely sure it was the same file, and it opened the new version correctly without the title bar. It seems the only way to make it run correctly is through the GUI.

Troubleshooting:

- as aforementioned, I edited the .desktop file to point to the new executable, but that didn't work
- I tried putting a symlink into `usr/local/bin/firefox` pointing at the new executable, but that didn't work either.
- I tried removing FF from my favorites on the dock, running the new version, *then* pinning it back to the favorites, but after closing and re-opening via the dock, I was greeted once again by the snap version.

Does anyone have some guidance to fix this? I'm at a loss.

Ubuntu 18.04  |  Firefox 80.0.1

Comment: Snap version?   Ubuntu desktop (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-desktop) ships by default with `firefox` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/firefox) which is not a *snap*.  Have you tried the default version? over a *snap* installed version?  (you may find you've got 3 versions installed; the original, an added *snap* version you mention &  the tarball version you've added)

Comment: @guiverc oops I had no idea what I was using. Yeah I saw snap in the `ps` I believe. Maybe I read something wrong. I think I just use the default version. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: To remove the snap version of firefox, and install firefox from the default repositories, use the command `sudo snap remove firefox && sudo apt install firefox`. The firefox in Ubuntu default repositories supports CSD titlebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Instead of deleting the question, I will answer and leave this up in the chance that someone else has a similar problem. All it took to fix was a logout and a login. Why does this work? I don't know, but my educated guess is
the launcher path is determined at login time. If anyone knows more about how this works, feel free to educate me. For now, I will mark this as resolved.

Comment: Hello Ryan, welcome to askubuntu.

you could accept your second answer as your final solution.